# Making jQuery image slider plugin play automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and JavaScript file for an image slider:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 1200,
    height: 350,
    navigation: false
  });
});
```

How do I make the slide play automatically?

Comment: Welcome to [so], The documentation shows how to start the image slider on load, but you'll need to show the example to see: http://www.slidesjs.com/#docs

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `auto: true` to make it autoplay

```
$('#slides').slidesjs({
   width: 940,
   height: 528,
   play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      restartDelay: 2500
   }
});
```